# Automapper- map long to DateTime c#

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to map a type `long` to a type `DateTime`? I have two classes with different fields:

First class:

```
public class Task
{    
    public int id_task { get; set; }    
    public string state{ get; set; }    
    public long date_prev { get; set; }    
    public long date_last { get; set; }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class TaskDTO
{    
    public int id_task { get; set; }    
    public string state{ get; set; }    
    public DateTime date_prev { get; set; }    
    public DateTime date_last { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map first class into second class:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostTask(Task task)
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<long, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter());
        cfg.CreateMap<Task, TaskDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.date_prev, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(task.date_prev)));
    });

    TaskDTO taskDTO = Mapper.Map<Task,TaskDTO>(task);

    /*...*/
}
```

But, when I run my app, I receive AutoMapper error :

> "ExceptionMessage": "Conversion not valid from 'Int64' to
>   'DateTime'.", "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidCastException",

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should be initializing your mapper once when your api starts up, not on every request!

Comment: Yep, i know. But i'm just trying to add automapper, this isn't the final version :)

Comment: What's wrong with https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters This is like the first thing you will find on google when typing automapper type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a mapping `long` -> `DateTime` that uses a custom `ITypeConverter` (as you already did):

```
public class TicksToDateTimeConverter: ITypeConverter<long, DateTime> {
    public DateTime Convert(long source, DateTime destination, ResolutionContext context) {
        return new DateTime(source); // interpret long as Ticks
    }
}

CreateMap<long, DateTime>().ConvertUsing<TicksToDateTimeConverter>();
```

Note that AutoMapper will automatically apply this rule if source is `long` and destination is `DateTime`, so the mapping for `TaskDTO` is just

```
CreateMap<Task, TaskDTO>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.date_prev, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.date_prev));
```

Comment: "public string Convert", should be "public DateTime Convert", but this helped :)